# How to efficiently count the number of occurrences of each word in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count the occurrences of each word in a file, such that the output is something like

```
the: 102
me: 100
etc
```

Here is the code I have so far.

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import string

filepath = Path('input.txt')

with open(filepath) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

word_list = sum((
    (s.strip('\n').translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).split(' ')
    for s in content
), [])

for key,value in Counter(word_list).items():
    print(f'{key} : {value}')
```

However, this takes infinite amount of time when the input file is large. How do I make this workable for large files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `f.readlines()` to directly iterating over f and `sum` to `list.extend` in a loop.

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import string

filepath = Path('input.txt')

with open(filepath) as f:
    word_list = []
    for s in f:
        word_list.extend((s.strip('\n').translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).split(' '))

for key,value in Counter(word_list).items():
    print(f'{key} : {value}')
```

works almost instantly on [my test file](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/64317/64317-0.txt).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!